# How to get the GROUP of a AD B2C user in a Blazor server side app after the user has logged in?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-identity-platform

I have a Blazor Server Side app with AD B2C login. I can login and get the claims with the following code.

```
public class Temp
{
    private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _auth;

    public Temp(AuthenticationStateProvider auth)
    {
        _auth = auth;
    }

    public async Task GetClaims()
    {
        var authState = await _auth.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var userClaims = authState.User.Claims;
    }
}
```

I created a **Group** called `Admin`and associated the user to that **Group**. How can I get that Group name `Admin` by using **Microsoft Identity**?

Comment: Hi did you check my answer? Is it helpful?

Comment: I did not, but I will in a few days

Answer (score 1):

Using Microsoft Graph [List memberOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) is the fastest way.

Please note you need to use an [AAD access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) rather than B2C access token for Microsoft Graph. Although [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-5-use-filter-and-odata-cast-to-get-groups-with-a-display-name-that-starts-with-a-including-a-count-of-returned-objects) mentions that we can use `filter` query with `displayName` property, but it doesn't work based on my practical testing. So we should query all the user's groups first:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/memberOf?$select=displayName
```

This will list all the group names which the user is a member of.

The `Admin` should be included in the list.